# Why output of command timedatectl list-timezones is only UTC?

Tags: timezone, systemd-timesyncd

In my Yocto distribution is installed the `systemd-timesyncd` service and the program `timedatectl`.
I have configured a UTC NTP Server in the file `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`. The `systemd-timesyncd` service works correctly and synchronizes date and time with the NTP server and so my system time is synchronized with the Universal Time (UTC).

I need to set my **timezone** and I know that I can use the command **timedatectl** ([Here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timedatectl.1.html) there is the manual page of timedatectl command).
In particular the command to execute is:
`timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>`
But when I execute:
`timedatectl list-timezones` to get the list of all timezones available the output of the command is:

```
> timedatectl list-timezones
UTC
```

I don't find any file `/usr/share/zoneinfo` or `/usr/zoneinfo`.

I think I miss installing something in my distribution but I don't know what..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Yocto installation I need to add following setting:

```
# In the following assignment note the space before the package name "tzdata" 
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " tzdata"
```

This installs the package `tzdata` and after this the command `timedatectl list-timezones` lists all timezones available.

In particular in my distribution the info about timezones are stored in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

Useful to find the solution is [this link](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2018-October/042964.html).